# Excluding self-intersections when performing a linestring difference in shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have a (complex) LineString (with 1 self-intersection):

```py
ls_self_intersection = LineString([(1, 2), (4, 2), (4, 3), (3, 3), (3, 1)])
```

[image]

and I have a (simple) LineString (with **no** self-intersection):

```py
ls = LineString([(2, 1), (2, 3)])
```

[image]

when I do a difference:

```py
ls_diff = ls_self_intersection.difference(ls)
```

the result is a MultiLineString

```py
mls = mapping(ls_diff)
```

with the following content

```py
{
    'type': 'MultiLineString',
    'coordinates': (
        ((1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0)),
        ((2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 2.0)),
        ((3.0, 2.0), (4.0, 2.0), (4.0, 3.0), (3.0, 3.0), (3.0, 2.0)),
        ((3.0, 2.0), (3.0, 1.0))
    )
}
```

I was expecting this result (excluding the self-intersection):

```py
{
    'type': 'MultiLineString',
    'coordinates': (
        ((1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0)),
        ((2.0, 2.0), (4.0, 2.0), (4.0, 3.0), (3.0, 3.0), (3.0, 1.0)))
    )
}
```

How can I exclude the self-intersection when performing the `difference` operation?

Comment: Could you compare the set of points in a post-processing step and remove those that are superfluous?

Comment: note: the result are linestrings. -> have not thought of this... :| you mean something like iterating over the original difference, concating the actual and the next linestring, performing difference on the concatenated linestrings with the other linestring (```ls```) to check if there is an intersection -> no: leave them concatenated and concatenate the next linestring, repeat difference... -> yes: concatenate next linestrings and perform a difference...
do you intend something like this?

Comment: Yes, correct, that could work this way in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is deep in GEOS library. It converts a complex line into a simple one containing non-crossing segments. Actually, that's a good thing. Otherwise, operations on complex geometries may produce incorrect results.

Comment: as you initially expected, the issue apparently lies inside the GEOS library -> https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/1068#issuecomment-765023089